# How do I create a bookmarklet that adds an infix to a URL?

Tags: javascript, regex, bookmarklet

I'd like to create a bookmarklet that loads the current page through my university's proxy server. It would make it much easier to access journals from Google Scholar and the like. I know how to append things to a URL, but I can't find out how to insert an infix at a particular point.

I want to take a URL like this:

```
http://www.jstor.org/stable/3167630
```

And turn it into this:

```
http://www.jstor.org.naomi.*universityname*.edu:2048/stable/3167630
```

How would I go about writing this bookmarklet?

Answer (score 0):

```
var mySiteURL = 'http://www.jstor.org/stable/3167630';
var firstPart = mySiteURL.substring(0, mySiteURL.indexOf(".org")+4);
var middlePart = '.naomi.*universityname*.edu:2048';
var lastPart = mySiteURL.substring(mySiteURL.indexOf(".org")+4, mySiteURL.length);
alert(firstPart + middlePart + lastPart);
```

start by grabbing the current url `window.location.href`. I'm assuming it always contains .org. Then do these string operations to change the url how you desire, and then navigate to it. `window.location.replace('https://www.google.com/');`

Answer (score 0):

This is the most robust that I could come up with:

```js
var string = "http://www.jstor.org/stable/3167630";
var regex = /(https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?.*?)\/(.*)/;
var result = string.replace(regex, function(match, m1, m2) {
  return m1 + ".naomi.*universityname*.edu:2048/" + m2;
});
alert(result);
```

In your bookmarklet you probably want to replace `string` by the window location.

Answer (score 0):

This RegEx should do the job:

```js
var proxyregex=/(https?:\/\/[0-9,a-z,A-Z,-,.]*)(.*)/;

var targetunc="http://www.jstor.org/stable/3167630";
var pattern="$1.naomi.*universityname*.edu:2048$2";

alert(targetunc.replace(proxyregex, pattern));
```